# Error while trying to compile and run sample module in Java

Tags: java, javac, java-11, java-platform-module-system, module-info

I'm new to the topic of modules, and I'm following a simple example of how to create, compile and run them.

The folder structure of my project is illustrated in the following diagram:

[image: osfar's project directory structure]

First I typed this in a cmd window to compile the module-info.java and Task.java files:

```sh
javac --module-path mods -d feeding feeding/zoo/animal/feeding/Task.java feeding/module-info.java
```

Then I tried to run the code with the following:

```sh
java --module-path feeding --module zoo.animal.feeding/zoo.animal.feeding.Task
```

I get the following error:

```sh
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: feeding
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Task.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
```

Can someone resolve this? Also, what is the role of the `--module-path` option in both the `java` and `javac` commands?

This is the code for the class and the module descriptor:

```java
module zoo.animal.feeding {
}
```

```java
public class Task {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("All fed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: The role for `--module-path` is documented in the `-help` section of both those tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward to solve as per what the error message reads.

> Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException:
> Task.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed
> in module)

Using the modulepath, a class is not allowed in the top-level directory of the project. So based on the directory structure, your `Task.java` file should include package description and look like -

```
package zoo.animal.feeding;
public class Task {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("All fed!");
    }
}
```

The compilation(from the command line directory where `mods` and `feeding` reside) would continue such as:

```
javac -d mods feeding/module-info.java feeding/zoo/animal/feeding/Task.java
```

should help you relevant `.class` files in the corresponding directories under `mods` as output folder. Then your execution using the following java command should work as expected.

```
java --module-path mods -m zoo.animal.feeding/zoo.animal.feeding.Task
```